# Creating Primary Key field on MVC class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and C#. I just stumbled on it and found it interesting. I encountered an issue which will not allow me proceed.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc; 

namespace MyHotel.Models
{
    public class AccountTypes
    {
        public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }
        public string AccountTypeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created the controler and the view thereafter.

And for this, I keep got this error:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'AccountTypes' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet "AccountTypes" is based on type "AccountTypes" that has no keys defined.
```

I google that the answers were to add   `[Key]` over the `public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }` so it could look like this:

```
namespace MyHotel.Models
{
    public class AccountTypes
    {
        [Key]
        public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }
        public string AccountTypeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But no result until now.
Note: I am using MVC 4

Comment: Generally, you normally would call this model object AccountType without an (s). That's the standard convention, which wouldn't require a Key attribute.

Comment: Are we supposed to be psychic?  What does "But no result till now" mean?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Description

Entity Framework CodeFirst recognize the key, by default, by name.
Valid names are `Id` or `<YourClassName>Id`.

Your property should named `Id` or `AccountTypesId`

Another way is to use the `ModelBuilder` to specify the key.

#### Sample

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AccountTypes> AccountTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountTypes>.HasKey(x => x.AccountTypeID);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

#### Mode Information

- [Entity Framework Code First Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2011/05/04/entity-framework-code-first-tutorial-supplement-what-is-going-on-in-a-fluent-api-call.aspx)

Comment: It was the difference in the property and model object naming patterns. I have it working now. Thanks.

Comment: this errors for me on the 2nd to last line at Entity<AccountTypes> stating  'DbModelBuilder.Entity<TEntityType>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context... could you still provide any help with this?

Comment: @tCoe Documenting the answer for future reference as I just hit the same problem. Just add a pair of brackets to that line after the Entity, like so: `modelBuilder.Entity<AccountTypes>().HasKey(x => x.AccountTypeID);`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)] property to indicate the key field.

The regular field would go with EntityKeyPropert=false.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
 {
  public DbSet<AccountTypes> AccountTypes { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
    modelBuilder.Entity<AccountTypes>().HasKey(x => x.AccountTypeID);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi Peter it seens you are missing an "s"

Your Account int should be:

public int AccountsTypeID { get; set; }

Hope it can be solved; Fernando.